# Is it possible to use Tkinter to create an app for Android or iOS?

Tags: python, android, ios, tkinter

I am trying to create an app and tkinter is really helpful, just want to confirm if Tkinter will successfully lead me to an app for IOS or Android.

Comment: Tkinter will not work, but you can try kivy

Comment: @rishi I have been trying to download Kivy but my laptop gives me an error

Comment: I haven't used kivy myself but have heard a lot about it. You can check this video out if you want to learn about itl, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bMHK6NDVlCM

Comment: @rishi I just checked the video out and did as it says but it still doesn't work as it doesn't have an download method for python 3.8.3 which I am using

Comment: Sorry as I said I haven't used kivy myself so I can't help you. However if you are really keen on developing apps I wouldn't suggest using python as it a very slow language and is not compatible with several devices. I suggest learning kotlin, java, flutter or react-native. I am planning to learn react-native as it seemed to have a nice syntax and easy to use.

Comment: @rishi I do intend on getting in that line but im still a student and this is part of my exam coursework. I was supposed to get help from a teacher but he cant come over due to corona and neither does he have wifi to teach me online so. I an stranded. I started coding with tkinter and had created a couple screens and I now realize that it wont work and my deadline is in September. I am stranded

Comment: I'm a student as well, do you have to make an app? Otherwise you can just compile it into an executable file for running on any computer.

Comment: @rishi yes I do I am doing OCR A level and this is an element of the exam. I have to code an app and submit the code.

Comment: Oh then I'm sorry I won't be able to help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219371/discussion-between-rishi-and-khushi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Tkinter won't work for creating mobile apps as it is meant to be used on desktop only. However check out Swift with Xcode that has a really good user interface for building app interfaces where you can drag and drop different items you want onto the screen - you will need a Mac for that.

Alternatively Android Studio is continually being updated which has a similar interface for creating app screens - available for Windows and Mac.

There are loads of tutorials for starting of on Xcode or Android Studio which should help you get started.

Answer (score 1):

`Tkinter` is meant for desktop applications, not mobile apps. You won't be able to make a mobile app with `Tkinter`. However, I've found that developing in `Tkinter` has given me a taste of what developing apps is like, and so I figure some of the thought processes I've learned will transfer over to `Swift` and `Java`, which are the main languages for developing mobile apps.

Comment: See [using-tkinter-programs-on-android](https://learning-python.com/using-tkinter-programs-on-android.html).