# Running python script with tkinter on iphone

Tags: python, ios, python-3.x, iphone, tkinter

not sure if possible, maybe someone has sucess

I have a little python script for my university exams and it will be great to show execution on the mobile. It uses tkinter for the GUI (I know, probably not the best, but it has been done like this)

I have it running on Android (not my phone) within Pydroid3 without any problem, but I can not replicate in iphone

so far i have tried Python3IDE and CodeSnackIDE (among others that can not get even python to work)

**Python3IDE**

- as it seems terminal do not support sudo, neither apt-get, no change to install tkinter

**CodeSnackIDE**

- successfully installed tkinter, using the instructions as:
  https://docs.codesnack-ide.com/Python-using-Pipenv-5a77effdbad44930b7927a37e25d4c45
  (after pipenv run sudo apt-get install python3-tk)

but i would say that the running is remote, and do not have display, can it be?
trying using tkinter raise the error:
couldn't connect to display :1

and after running export DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY
(as [local machine _tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display ":0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59006466/local-machine-tkinter-tclerror-couldnt-connect-to-display-0))
couldn't connect to display unix:1

**Am I trying something never done before?**
or something not meant to be done ... :_(

I know there is posts like:
[Is it possible to use Tkinter to create an app for Android or iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63292696/is-it-possible-to-use-tkinter-to-create-an-app-for-android-or-ios)

and not sure if this fully applies